# How to accomplish a certain multiplication in tensorflow

Tags: matrix, tensorflow

I have one tensor `A` of dimension `[a,b,c,d]`, and another `B` of dimension `[b,b,d,e]`, and `C`, a list of `[a]` integers from 0 to `b`. I need to produce the tensor `D` of dimension `[a,b,c,e]` given by

`D[i,j,k,l] = sum for m=0..d of   A[i,C[i],k,m] * B[C[i],j,m,l]`

`b` is small enough (3 or 5, usually?) that I don't mind doing this in `b` separate operations -- but I can't afford the waste by going to something that takes `b^2` memory or time, when this operation clearly should be linear in `b`. This seems like it will be some combination of pointwise multiplies (with broadcasting?) and tensor contractions (a matrix multiply across the common `m` dimension), but I can't pin it down.

If someone can really convince me that this isn't possible in `O(b)` flops with tensorflow's provided operations, then okay, but then I'd want an `O(b^2)` for sure.

Update: It's looking like the appropriately modified `A` tensors can be built individually using `tf.gather_nd`; if this can then be paired up with `B` somehow, maybe? Unfortunately my experiments in this so far led to finding a bug in `tf.gather_nd` itself which has slowed things down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to accomplish this, reasonably efficiently. First build a modified version of `B` with `tf.gather`, with the appropriate parts in the first index:

```
B2 = tf.gather(B, C)
```

Then pull out just the relevant parts of the `A` tensor using `tf.gather_nd`. We're going to pull out a bunch of pairs of indices of the form `[0,C[0]], [1,C[1]], [2,C[2]]...` and so on, so first we need to build the index tensor.

```
a = tf.shape(A)[0]
A2_indices = tf.stack([tf.range(a), C], axis=0)
A2 = tf.gather_nd(A, A2_indices)
```

producing `A2` with shape `[a,c,d]`. Now we need to multiply `A2` and `B2` appropriately. It's tensor contraction in the `m` indices (2 and 3, respectively) but pointwise multiplication in the `i` index (0 in both). This means that, sadly, the resulting item isn't tensor contraction or pointwise multiplication! One option would be computing the tensor product and contracting only over `m`, and then taking `tf.diag` over the two `i` indices -- but this would waste a lot of computation building the rest of a matrix that we don't need. Instead, we can think of this as a *batched matrix multiplication*: this used to be called `tf.batched_matmul` but now it's just `matmul`. This has the caveat, though, that besides the 2 matrix dimensions in each input tensor, the rest all have to be pointwise multiplies. `B` and `B2` fail this criterion, because they have the additional `j` index. But, we could "wrap that in" with the `l` output dimension, and then remove it later. This means first calling `tf.transpose` to put `j` and `l` next to each other, then  `tf.reshape` to turn into one `j*l` output dimension, then doing `tf.matmul`, then another `tf.reshape` and `tf.transpose` to return to the original form. So

```
a, b, d, e = B2.get_shape().as_list()
B2_trans = tf.transpose(B2, perm=[0,2,1,3])
B2_jl = tf.reshape(B2, [a,d,b*e])
product_jl = tf.matmul(A2, B2_jl)
product_trans = tf.reshape(product_jl, [a,d,b,e])
result = tf.transpose(product_trans, perm=[0,2,1,3])
```

Which finishes it up! Of course in practice it may well be that `B` is only needed in this one instance, in which case it may be that `B` can start out already in the "compressed" state, saving a transpose (and a cheap reshape); or if `A2` is going to be flattened or transposed anyway then it could also save a transpose. But overall everything is pretty minimal complexity. :)